# ForceCode takes very long to load

Tags: visualstudiocode, forcecode

I have VS code v1.77.2 and ForceCode v4.0.5 installed on a Windows machine.  ForceCode takes more than 15 mins to load. It was suggested to re-install it, but that did not work. Any insight of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) is the officially supported extension bundle. For support from a third-party bundle, you need to contact that author. You may want to [log an issue](https://github.com/celador/ForceCode/issues/416). In the meantime, consider using the an extension bundle that uses the standard SEP. I personally recommend [Codefriar's Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codefriar.codefriar-s-pack), it's the standard SEP plus a number of great extensions to make your life easier.